Algoritmo para hallar la cantidad de números Armstrong de los 10 números generados a partir del input number_init. Solo puedo usar while e if anidados
def numerosArmstrong(number_init, step):

    i = number_init
    count = 0

    while i <= number_init + 10:
        post_numeros = number_init + 1
        suma = 0
        digito = 0
        while post_numeros > 0:
            digito = post_numeros % 10
            suma = suma + (digito ** 4)
            post_numeros //= 10
            if suma == post_numeros:
                count = count + 1

            number_init = number_init + step
            i = i + 1
        return count

Si ingreso 8208 como number_init y 1 de step debería darme de resultado 1 ya que 8208 es igual a la suma de cada dígito elevado a la cuarta: 8 ** 4 + 2 ** 4 + 0 ** 4 + 8 ** 4. Pero no me esta funcionando el código. Solo puedo usar while e if anidados dentro de una función. No puedo usar listas ni for ni ningún otro tipo de condicionales.
Un numero armstrong es aquel numero que al separar sus dígitos, elevarlos a la cuarta a cada uno y luego sumarlos dan el numero que eran loa dígitos juntos. Ejemplo: 8028 es un numero armstrong ya que todos sus dígitos elevados a la cuarta y luego sumarlos dan 8028.

Edita tu pregunta para explicar qué es un Número Armstrong.

Ya actualize lo que es un numero armstrong en la descripción debajo del codigo, gracias!

¿Que se supone que debe hacer la función? ¿contar los números armstrong (AKA narcicistas) partiendo de number_init, de step en step hasta tener 10 números? Es decir, para numerosArmstrong(8208, 5) sería contar los números narcicistas existentes en [8208, 8213, 8218, 8223, 8228, 8233, 8238, 8243, 8248, 8253] ¿o es otra cosa?

Si pones el input que sea 8208, desde ahi se generan 10 números dependiendo del step. SI pones el step 1 los siguientes números generados serán desde 8208 hasta 8218. Y dentro de ese rango de números contar cuantos números armstrong hay y devolver en el output cuantos números armstrong hay.

Del "8208 hasta el 8218" serían 11 en total, 10 generados más el inicial ¿es así? ¿o serian 10 en total incluido el inicial, es decir, desde 8208 hasta 8217 ambos incluidos? Otra cosa, harcodeas el exponente de las potencias (el número de dígitos de cada número a comprobar) supongo que no siempre serán números de cuatro dígitos ¿o si?

Hola, serian 10 generados mas el inicial correcto. Me falto comentar eso. No, no siempre serán números de cuatro dígitos.

Tu función tiene varios problemas:

Te estas complicando mucho a la hora de iterar las veces necesaria y generar los 10 números. El numero de iteraciones es conocido de antemano, son 11 (comprobar el numero inicial y generar/comprobar los diez siguientes), por lo tanto, simplemente haz algo como:
  i = 0
  while i < 11:
      ...
      i += 1


Además de sumar step, incrementas el numero inicial y los generados en uno en cada iteración (post_numeros = number_init + 1), con lo que terminas comprobando el número incorrecto.

La comprobación de la suma (if suma == post_numeros:) debes hacerla cuando termine el ciclo encargado de calcularla. Es decir, ese condicional debe ir fuera del segundo while, justo cuando termine el mismo.

Un número es Armstrong (quizás mas conocido como número narcisista) si es igual a la suma de sus dígitos elevados a la potencia de su número de cifras.
Ahora mismo hardcodeas el exponente de la potencia en 4 (el número de dígitos de cada número a comprobar), pero dado que los números pueden tener más o menos de cuatro dígitos, deberás calcularlos antes de calcular las potencias.
Si no puedes usar otros métodos típicos (como len(str(numero))) para calcular el numero de dígitos, siempre puedes usar de nuevo la división entera entre 10. Es ineficiente porque la aplicas dos veces, pero si no puedes usar otros recursos ni contenedores, quedan pocas opciones...


Con todo, podría quedar algo así:
def numerosArmstrong(number_init, step):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    while i < 11:
        num = number_init
        num_digs = 1
        while (num := num // 10) > 0:
            num_digs += 1

        num = number_init
        suma = 0
        while num > 0:
            suma += (num % 10) ** num_digs
            num //= 10
            
        if suma == number_init:
            count += 1

        number_init += step
        i += 1
        
    return count


Gracias por indicarme donde me he equivocado. Algo puntual que no sabia, ya que es la primera vez que me piden un ejercicio asi, es que los dígitos se elevan a la potencia de su numero de cifras. Muchas gracias!
